# SAPUI5 for older versions of SAP UI

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I would like to use SAPUI5 for customers who are on previous versions of SAP.

Couple of customers expressed interest in Fiori but their SAP upgrade plan is far from now. I am exploring options to use SAPUI5 framework alone with alternative options.

I am thinking to use a Java EE server / Tomcat to deploy these applications and integrate to the backend over RFC.

One can easily think of using OpenUI5 but there are many controls and libraries are not available here. For example, viz is a library that comes with lot of Reporting related controls is not available in OpenUI5. I want to know how can i use SAPUI5 controls or framework in this respect.

Comment: We can easily think of Angular, JQuery, Node, D3 or any other frameworks in the market. My idea is to use SAPUI5 across all SAP enterprise applications!!! I want to know the road blocks or licensing issues or technical issues that come in my way. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, all **SAP** Customers can use `SAPUI5` with the licenses that they have already in place, e.g., SAP NetWeaver developers license enables you to develop with SAPUI5, same if you have a developer license for SAP NW Cloud.

So for SAP customers or partners, it is expected to be just an additional offering that is covered by the existing contracts.

Beyond the technical perspective, there is a **difference regarding support**: for SAP customers SAPUI5 comes with support agreements, so SAP guarantees bugfixing. These support guarantees are naturally not coming with the completely free Open Source version of UI5.

Answer (score 1):

if the customer has a valid license  for development as outlined by Sunil, then i think you can also deploy the SAPUI5 library itself on a separate server (like  a NetWeaver java or a tomcat ) to make use of it inside your custom applications.

But for Fiori applications you should rather consider the cloud offerings from SAP, as you will need not only SAPUI5 as a library but also a capable backend system where the fiori apps are deployed and it probably won't work on older releases.

Nevertheless, You can find the Java Package of SAPUI5 in the "UISAPUI5_JAVA" package, there should be a deployable version for inside (e.g. SAP Note 2176845).

Or consider OpenUI5. You are right that not all libraries are included, but almost all libraries needed for creating applications are shipped also with OpenUI5. You can also create charts direclty with D3, it is even shipped as a third party library with OpenUI5.

Hope that helps.
Michael

Comment: Hi Michael, yes that is a good info....How can i mix fiori cloud offering with SAP older versions? Can they run independently & how are they integrated with SAP systems? Is it like Fiori app on cloud + OData / RFC from Backend? Is this Fiori cloud dependent on HCP? Can you share little more information and what are they?